# can't import pydbg

Tags: python-2.7, pydbg

when I import the pydbg, it shows the information like the picture !

[image]

who can help me to solve it ? thanks very much !

I use window 10 64bit, python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Try using  x86 version of python 2.7. That will solve the problem.